# Is it possible for asp.net and asp.net core projects to "play nice" in the same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am wondering if an `asp.net project` and an `asp.net core project` can "play nice" together in the same visual studio solution. (.sln)

I am new to both frameworks and am having trouble researching the compatibility of the two due to the whole naming ambiguity...

When I start a new asp.net core project we have the home controller with a few views that are .cshtml

Would I be able to add and leverage pre-existing .aspx files that are from another project? 
Or is it a fool's task and converting them a necessity?

Comment: Yes it is possible and works quite well.  The key is targeting the correct framework version.  If you have dependencies that haven't been ported to use .net core then you will need to target a specific .net framework (e.g. 4.6.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. If you are new to both frameworks, forget about web forms, just go for asp.net core. If you need to get help, and want to google the answer, just search the last year, or from Jan 2016.

Converting aspx files is easy. Copy the HTML output to the View and change it with Razor. Then take the existing code and put it in two methods on the controller, one for the page view, and one for taking the response action.